# How to print only certain characters from a line using python

Tags: python

For example, I have:

```
a = (b ^ c) || d && e
```

I want it to print only

```
^ || &&
```

I am new to python. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide an example block of code of what you've tried?

Comment: In your example, how would it decide to print those two spaces but none of the others?

Comment: What is the character set that you are trying to extract?

Answer (score 1):

We can filter out the unwanted characters with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> a = "(b ^ c) || d && e"
>>> print(*filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha() and x not in '()', a), sep='')
 ^  ||  &&
```

Or, if you don't want multiple spaces or leading/trailing spaces:

```
>>> print(''.join(filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha() and x not in '()', a)).replace('  ',' ').strip())
^ || &&
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by the undesired character groups and then proceed to join and strip space:

```
' '.join(re.split(r'[\s\d\w()]+', a)).strip() # remove numbers, letters, and whitespace
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit1**

To correct misunderstanding I can suggest use regexp for this.

```
import re
print(re.sub(r"[^\^|\|\||\&\&]", "", a))
```

**Edit2**

Comments for code above.

*re.sub()* function replaces by second parameter all tokens that match given pattern. Quick training you can pass here [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/)

That part of code finds all yours symbols using given regex and replaces them by empty string.

```
r"[^\^|\|\||\&\&]"
```

That regex has a folowing parts

[^] - that tells find all symbols that not between [ and ]. ^ symbol used for negation.

\^\^ - your ^^ symbols shielded using backslashes

\|\| - your || symbols

\&\& - your && symbols

All of them grouped using "or" statement ( "|" symbol )

In the end you have

^^ | || | && without backslashes tells, find ^^ or || or &&

and in [^ ^^ | || | &&], finds every symbol that not ^^ or || or &&

But if you coding at first time, or you don't know python syntax yet, i recommend you just learn python at simplest examples, and after that learn regex syntax.

Comment: I suspect the OP wanted to print only those characters, _starting from the given string_.

Comment: Yea, basically in a given expression, I want to print only the operations which are going on. I have a piece of C++ code and need to extract just the operations in each line of the code..

Comment: How do I specify that I want to print only if it finds "&&" and not when it finds "&" ?

Comment: @Rashmi, I just expand my answer, because your question to general again for me, and I can't give you a clear answer again.